# After updating the xcode fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift

After an update has stopped working program.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate {

    var interstring = [LogItem]()

    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    var logTableView = UITableView()

    let photoVC = PhotoViewController()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "\"LogItem\""
        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return interstring.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            ***let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell*** - This emphasizes this part of the code

            let logItem = interstring[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel!.text = logItem.valueForKey("title") as? String

            return cell
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"LogItem")

        var error: NSError?

        let fetchedResults =
        managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest,
            error: &error) as? [LogItem]
        println("\(interstring)")

        if let results = fetchedResults {
            interstring = results
            //self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

All Projects is [**here**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3a8gallgukr9bm4/Core-Data_515.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Can you specify the line where it gives you the error?

Comment: ***let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell*** - This emphasizes this part of the code

Comment: In my case, couldn't get `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_ :)`to work on Swift 2 (the compiler suggested that I use `!` in the cast, eventhough I was already using `!`). Changing to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_ : forIndexPath:) ` did the trick...

Comment: ...perhaps that can help you too. Also, did you register the cell class for identifier with the table view?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean ?!

Answer (score 0):

I also had this same problem when updating to swift 2 and xcode 7.

I think the problem is that you're trying to call a cell that doesn't exist. I fixed the problem by creating a nib with a custom cell and then setting the identifier to "cell" as well as initialising the nib

```
let identifier = "cell"
var cell: customCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? customCell

if cell == nil {

   tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "customCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
   cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? customCell

}
```

Hope that helps